# Django ManyToMany to Multiple Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7, manytomanyfield

I have models A, B, C.

These models are related in the following manner.

C in addition to other things, contains a collection of Pairs of B and C.

So I created a model X, that contains Foreign keys to C, A and B.

This allows me to define multiple A,B pairs that can be tied to C.

After reading through documentation, it looks like the ManyToManyField in the model class would be useful for this, but I couldn't find any instance of having multiple tables being involved. All documentations is generally useful for tying between for example: C and A.

I can't merge A and B of course, otherwise this question wouldn't be here.
Any suggestions on how to do this without creating model X and just let this be handled by Django's model framework?

Comment: You need to give an example please. OR your current code in order to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: what is wrong with having a model C and two manytomany fields to B and A?

Comment: @DanialTz The pairing of A, B is important, ex: if A={1,2}, and B={a,b}, then if I only wanted C to relate to 1, a and 2, b, it wouldn't be possible via what you suggest, at least I am unable to see how.

Answer (score 0):

If this fits the overall logic of your modelling, you could pair A and B through a [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation, and then hold a ManyToMany relation from C to either A or B.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unfortunately that was not feasible. What I ended up doing though is to create a separate table for A-B, and then doing Many-to-Many with C, which ended up suiting my overall schema better anyway. Thanks